# Custom Delegates

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa, cocoa-touch

I've read in a number of places that using the AppDelegate as the heart of the application is bad (apart from the actual UIApplication delegates themselves).

Would it be wise to create custom delegate classes to keep code modularized.

For example if I need to format various text inputs, create a Formatter delegate class and set the delegate on any text input object that needs to be formatted?

Does that make sense?

Comment: I am not sure why you would need a delegate design pattern for a text formatter.  Could you not just use a call to a class method that returns the formatted text as the result.

Comment: I am using that as a scenario, pure example only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The point of the articles you've read is 'Do not keep all application logic in app delegate'. Responsibility of app delegate is to handle important events in app lifecycle in lightweight way by notifying appropriate parts of application, not to manage views or data flows or network calls. For example in `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` delegate usually adding root controller's view into window, makes this window active and leaves everything else to controller.

Comment: So, putting IBActions and IBOutlets in the app delegate is acceptable?

Comment: If you take a look at app newly created you'll notice that app delegate already has some `IBOutlet`s in it. You can have them in app delegate just don't overuse it. Controller is better place usually to handle actions from controls and such.